# How can I upload a video to youtube with Windows Phone?

Tags: video

From the camera roll, I can select a video then hit the ellipsis for sharing options. However, only 'share on OneDrive ...' is listed on the menu and under (or, under 'share...').

Is there any way to upload the raw video directly to YouTube?

Alternately, is there a quick/clever/automatic way to go from OneDrive -> YouTube?

Comment: Using a Upload to YouTube app. you can do it.. http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/upload-to-youtube/b82133ab-2fcb-4dda-a626-cb9e091ab23c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft just released a YouTube version (3.2.0.0) and one of many features is upload videos.

Just open the app and in the top left corner you add your account. After that you can see the upload option.

[image]

You can find the app here: http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=dcbb1ac6-a89a-df11-a490-00237de2db9e

**Edit**

Sorry, Google had black listed the app and now they are fighting with Microsoft saying that the Microsoft should make a html5 app instead a native one. Different from what iOS and Android.

**Edit 2**

Nokia has a video uploaded that looks like works for any Lumina. It is available here:[Nokia Video Upload](http://www.wpcentral.com/nokia-video-upload-heads-all-lumias-no-gdr2-requirement)

Comment: Doesn't work :(

Comment: I added a new app. @FactorMystic is that answer your question? ;)

Comment: Limited solution only for Lumia phones, but that's sufficient

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this natively, but there are 3rd party apps you can download that offer this.

If my memory serves me, I believe [EasyTube](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=76cb1d4f-432b-4adf-a6f5-d90d53197b99) is one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Nokia Lumia phone, there is a Nokia app called 'Nokia Video Upload', that you could use.

I'm not sure, but it's possible that it is only available for WP8 Nokia phones.